# Runas SC stop remote service with spaces

Tags: cmd, syntax-error, runas

I am using the [sc](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) command to remotely restart a process under [runas](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html). This works perfectly with a service that has no spaces, but if it has spaces, forcing me to use `'` inside the `runas "command"` quotes, it fails and cannot find the service.

I have already checked the properties of this particular service to ensure the service name (it is the same as the display name).

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Prompt for Domain & Username. Password will be prompted when run.
set /P Domainn=Enter Domain Name:
set /P Usern=Enter Username:

set service=workingservice
REM set service='Not a working service'

REM Define Start Stops
set userrunasstop=runas /profile /user:%domainn%\%usern% "sc \\%domainn% stop %service%"
set userrunasstart=runas /profile /user:%domainn%\%usern% "sc \\%domainn% start %service%"

:optionmenu
CLS
ECHO 1 - Stop Service
ECHO 2 - Start Service
ECHO q - Quit
ECHO.
set /P optionnum=Enter command number:
GOTO option%optionnum%

:option1
REM Stop Client
%userrunasstop%

goto optionmenu

:option2
REM Start Client
%userrunasstart%

goto optionmenu

:optionq
EXIT
```

This script works great as shown, but when I comment out `set service=workingservice` and un-comment `set service='Not a working service` it doesn't work. Also, if I use `runas` to open its open cmd.exe, I can then successfully run the `sc` command with quotes around the service name.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a workaround for this issue by opening up a new command prompt under `runas`. And in the new command prompt calling another bat file that executes the `sc stop service` command. This removes the multiple quoting that was causing the error.

I am still working on passing variables from the `runas` batch file to the `sc` batch file to allow the `%domain%` variable to be input into the `sc` command.

#### File `runas.bat`

```
set /P Domainn=Enter Domain Name:
set /P Usern=Enter Username:

runas /profile /user:%domainn%\%usern% "cmd sc.bat"
```

#### File `sc.bat` (minus all the frills in the original script)

```
set service='Service with spaces'
sc \\domainname stop %service%
```